# Get utc offset value from a local timestamp string in nodejs/javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, utc, timezone-offset

My local timestamp value is a string in the below format:
'2020-05-19T15:45:07.2306062+05:30'

How can i get a UTC offset value from this format of date string using nodejs/javascript?

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the offset using the following:

```
var trimmedDate = '2020-05-19T20:16:56.2306062+05:30'.slice(0,-6)
var localtimestamp = new Date(trimmedDate)
var difference = new Date()-localtimestamp;
var offset = Math.trunc(difference/(1000*60));
```